# How to separate array of comma separated string into various arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What's the best way to convert this array of comma separated values

```
[ 'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on' ]
```

Into three arrays?

```
[ 'com--test',           [ LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5Ilsdf4cKN4q2', ['on',
  'com--fxtrimester',      SEzMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmlkdfqkPczCl2',  'on',
  'com--fxtrimester' ]     LFutksdfx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5I4cKN4q2 ]  'on']
```

I was trying something like:

```
 var indexToSplit = unique.indexOf(',');
 var status = unique.slice(3, indexToSplit - 1);
 var use = unique.slice(2, indexToSplit - 2);
 var pros = unique.slice(0, indexToSplit - 3);
 console.log(pros);
```

But I figured that is wrong ... any help is appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean three arrays? ['on', 'on', 'on'] is one of the array?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear... first array would be the com--test kind.
Second one the Lsdhfbsdhfbsifashdbaisdq2 strings , and third the 'on' values.

Comment: It's an extremely weird way to format the three arrays. :)

Comment: and quick to make the question and to you guys understand too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to loop over array and use `string.split` to get seperate parts.

Once you have seperate parts, you can push them to necessary array;

```js
var d = [ 'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on'];

var result = [[],[],[]];
var len = 3;
d.forEach(function(str, i){
  var _tmp = str.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i<len; i++){
    result[i].push(_tmp[i])
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

---

A little generic way.

- Loop over data and split each string using comma(`,`)
- Loop over split values and check if necessary array exists.
- If not, initialise array, but you cannot do `p[i] = []` as this will push to first value. You will have to also initialise all previous values. For this, you can use `new Array(length)`. By default, if `length` is greater than `0`, all indexes will be initialise to `undefined`.
- Now push to necessary array. Position will be maintained.

```js
var d = ['com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on,test'
];


var result = d.reduce(function(p, c, index) {
  var _tmp = c.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < _tmp.length; i++) {
    // Check if position not defined.
    if (p[i] === undefined)
      // Initialize array and add default (undefined) to all elements before current element
      p[i] = new Array(index);

    p[i].push(_tmp[i])
  }
  return p;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :-)

Comment: @arnoldssss I have added a generic solution that will eliminate need for `len=3`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question does not ask for a more general case, i am safely assuming it for 3 array. We can use forEach function on array below code can be one amongst the possible solutions

```js
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
var arr3 = [];

var x = ['com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on', 'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on', 'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on']

x.forEach(function(data) {
  var dataArray = data.split(',');
  arr1.push(dataArray[0]);
  arr2.push(dataArray[1]);
  arr3.push(dataArray[2]);
});


console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: Please add explanation. Just adding working code is not good enough.

Comment: added :) , will keep in mind from next time . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `map` this becomes:

- for positions X out of 0, 1 and 2:
- convert each item in the list into an array, and choose the Xth item

```js
var start = [ 'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on' ]


var out = [0,1,2].map(i => 
  start.map(x => x.split(',')[i]) )
console.log(out)
```